# Unet how to control child gameobject?

Tags: unity, debugging, unet

I'm currently getting into the Unity networking system called unet. I have a child of the local player authority, the weapon. The weapon (PlasmaCannon_left and right) have a script handling firing, because weapons can be replaced, and have different firing intervals, this seemed to me to be the easier way. However, they won't fire.

Hierarchy:

[image]

(simplified) Weapon Code:

```
public void Start() {
    Debug.Log("Weapon Spawned.");
    if (isLocalPlayer) {
        Debug.Log("Weapon set as local player");
    }
}

public void Update() {
    if (isLocalPlayer) {
        if (firingTimer <= firingInterval){
            firingTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (firingTimer >= firingInterval) {
            if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && firingMode == FiringMode.Primary) {
                CmdFire();
            }
            if (Input.GetButton("Fire2") && firingMode == FiringMode.Secondary) {
                CmdFire();
            }
        }
    }
}

[Command]
public void CmdFire() {
    Debug.Log("Firing Bullet.");
}
```

I am getting the "Weapon Spawned." log message, but nothing inside `isLocalPlayer` conditions is happening even though I have added a `networkidentity` component and set `Local Player Authority` to true.

Like I said, I'm still learning so I have no clue what's going wrong here.

Comment: You do not have the `"Weapon set as local player"` log message right? Then the `isLocalPlayer` variable must be at false. Can you put a breakpoint to check?

Comment: ^ I agree, try printing out isLocalPlayer before that if instead of just saying "Weapon Spawned." and see if it gives false (it probably does) and find out why it does. We don't have the rest of your code so we don't know what the class of isLocalPlayer is let alone why it doesn't work. (is it even a boolean or an int or something you can check for true vs false? is it ever being set or just initialized?) Does this object even have access to that variable?

Comment: yes, it is false, what i cant figure out is why it is false. it's a child of the player gameobject.

Comment: alright, from what i've been able to figure out the problem is that the prefab gets spawned, but its children don't have client authority. do i really need to loop through the prefab and spawn each child seperately with client authority, or is there some easier way?

Comment: @realUser404 Breakpoints unfortunately don't work in unity.

Comment: @KevinKuyl, actually, they do.

Comment: @Gnemlock i apologize, you're right. just not when pressing play in the editor. But do you have any idea why, when i spawn a child (simply by instantiating a prefab, setting its parent, and spawning it on the server) isLocalPlayer is false? to my understanding children of the local player should inherit this value as true.

Comment: @KevinKuyl First you should make sure your "Player gameobject" has its `isLocalPlayer` variable set to true. If it is not the case, you should find out why. If it is set to true, then you can use `base.isLocalPlayer` instead and it should work!

Comment: @KevinKuyl did you try out?

Comment: @realUser404 i figured out the problem may be a lot deeper than i initially thought. the player gameobject doesn't even get spawned properly. seems i still have a lot to learn about unet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason `isLocalPlayer` is not inherited from its parent, the gameobject also did not have client authority, i solved it by calling a function in the `PlayerController` to actually fire the bullet, only using variables used in the weapon/bullet objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isLocalPlayer) {
    Debug.Log("Weapon set as local player");
}
```

This wont work if it is a child of the gameobject with local authority (the network manager recognizes the parent gameobject as the local player).

Instead, try checking "if" the gameobject is a child of the gameobject recognized as the local player. Using your example...

```
    if (!gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().isLocalPlayer)
    {
        Debug.Log("Weapon set as local player");
    }
```

Now see if the debug message is displayed. Note: For anyone else coming across the net, just replace the debug message with "return;" as you would normally using that function.